# How do I make a "notify" box disappear

Tags: krl

When I respond to a web event, I would like to make a previously actioned(?) notify box disappear. Is there a KRL way to tell it to go away or does it have to be done through javascript?

If it must be done through javascript, please provide an example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## New Shiny Awesomer Answer!

All my previous answers suck! What you really should do is trigger the click event on the close button.

```
$K(".kGrowl-notification .close").trigger("click");
```

Just emit that JavaScript when you are responding with a web event.

**Better example app:**

```
ruleset a60x469 {
  meta {
    name "better-close-notify-example"
    description <<
      better-close-notify-example
    >>
    author "Mike Grace"
    logging on
  }

  rule put_notify_on_page {
    select when pageview ".*"
    {
      // put notify on page
      notify("Hello","I'm on your page") with sticky = true;

      // raise web event
      emit <|
        setTimeout(function() {
          app = KOBJ.get_application("a60x469");
          app.raise_event("clear_notify");
        }, 2000);
      |>;
    }
  }

  rule clear_notify {
    select when web clear_notify
    {
      emit <|
        $K(".kGrowl-notification .close").trigger("click")
      |>;
    }
  }
}
```

---

## OLD CRAPPY ANSWER

---

There are several ways you could accomplish this.

- [emit](http://docs.kynetx.com/docs/Emit) JavaScript to hide or replace notification
- change style to display:none with [set_element_attr](http://docs.kynetx.com/docs/Set_element_attr)
- [replace_inner action](http://docs.kynetx.com/docs/Replace_inner) to remove the notification (evil)

**Examples:**

set_element_attr

```
set_element_attr(".kGrowl", "style", "display:none");
```

emit [remove] (evil)

```
emit <|
  $K(".kGrowl").remove();
|>;
```

emit [hide]

```
emit <|
  $K(".kGrowl").hide();
|>;
```

replace_html (evil)

```
replace_html(".kGrowl","");
```

**Full app example:**

```
ruleset a60x468 {
  meta {
    name "example-clear-notify"
    description <<
      example-clear-notify
    >>
    author "Mike Grace"
    logging on
  }

  rule put_notify_on_page {
    select when pageview ".*"
    pre {
      button =<<
        <button id="clear-notify">Click me to clear the notify</button>
      >>;
    }
    {
      notify("Hello","I'm on your page") with sticky = true;
      append("body", button);
      emit <|
        $K("#clear-notify").click(function() {
          app = KOBJ.get_application("a60x468");
          app.raise_event("clear_notify");
        });
      |>;
    }
  }

  rule clear_notify {
    select when web clear_notify
    {
      replace_inner(".kGrowl","");
    }
  }
}
```

**Example app bookmarklet: =>** http://mikegrace.s3.amazonaws.com/forums/stack-overflow/example-clear-notify-dev_bookmarklet.html

**Example app run on example.com:**

[image]

**clear button clicked:**

[image]

Comment: I didn't know that we had a set_element_attr action!

Comment: I like the new shiny answer. :)